# Two thumbs with the slider of Material component for android?

Tags: android, slider, material-design, material-components, android-slider

on [the sliders presentation](https://material.io/components/sliders/#) of the Material.io website they show the double thumbs slider below, but I can't find how to enable it, and I didnt really find any docs. Is it available for the android component?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
Add the `RangeSlider` component in your layout. Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/slider_multiple_thumbs"            
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="10"
        ../>
```

Then use the method [**`setValues()`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.0-alpha05/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider.java#L631):

```
RangeSlider slider = findViewById(R.id.slider_multiple_thumbs);
slider.setValues(1.0f,5.0f);
```

The final result:

[image]

**Note:** This requires a minimum of version **1.2.0-beta01**

Pls note that:

- each value must be greater or equal to `valueFrom`, and less or equal to `valueTo`. If that is not the case, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.
- if the slider is in discrete mode, the values must be set to a value that falls on a tick. if that is not the case, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

---

With **Compose** you can use the `RangeSlider`:

```
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f..100f) }

    RangeSlider(
        modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Localized Description" },
        value = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
        valueRange = 0f..100f,
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
            // viewModel.updateSelectedSliderValue(sliderPosition)
        },
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is now available in the alpha-05-release: [material-components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases)
Use it by calling `setValues()` with two values to enable two thumbs.

Answer (score 2):

**[2022 Update]**

Now it exists `RangeSlider`.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material.RangeSlider
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember

var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f..100f) }
Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
RangeSlider(
    values = sliderPosition,
    onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
    valueRange = 0f..100f,
    onValueChangeFinished = {
        // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
        // viewModel.updateSelectedSliderValue(sliderPosition)
    },
)
```

You can find all the documentation here: [Material RangeSlider Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#RangeSlider(kotlin.ranges.ClosedFloatingPointRange,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.ranges.ClosedFloatingPointRange,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.SliderColors))